# Did more people watch Infowars than CNN?

Tags: media, television

At 2:13 in the HBO documentary "The Truth vs Alex Jones" (2024), attorney Mark Bankston claims that at the height of its success, "more people watched Infowars at any given hour than CNN".

Is that claim true? I find it very hard to believe.

Comment: Does it give any indication of when "at the height of its [Infowars?] success" is? I would guess during the 2016 election, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @Laurel I believe it was 2015 or so? He doesn't say.

Comment: I'm guessing the claim is based on another that he "convinced nearly a quarter of all Americans that 20 six- and seven-year-olds weren’t murdered in December 2012", rather than pure/direct audience https://www.salon.com/2024/03/26/truth-vs-alex-jones-max-sandy-hook/

Comment: Whats your metric? 

The quote could mean that withing an hour more distinct people watch a 1 minute video on infowars than CNN have distinct viewers in the same hour. or it could mean that if i select a specific hour infowars have a higher maximum distinct viewer count at the same time. Or it could mean that I count simultaneous viewers, but count the same occurrence of an identical user as separate watchtime - or do we count the hits. Should one include international viewers? Unless we specify a little better what we mean by it its unclear.

Comment: @Sascha During show broadcast hours, more people were listening/watching Alex Jones than the concurrent program on CNN. Not including rewatch numbers. That's how I would define it at least.

Answer (score -3):

It's not possible to get exact viewing counts as those would be published from Alex Jones so there is no way to confirm accuracy, and I could not find these numbers nonetheless.

Going off of the other users answer about visits, we can analyze web visits for viewers. According to SimilarWeb, [infowars.com got 6.2 million](https://www.similarweb.com/website/infowars.com/#overview) web visits in the last month.

[image]

[cnn.com has 497.7 million](https://www.similarweb.com/website/cnn.com/#overview) web visits in the last month.

[image]

I think it is safe to assume CNN has a greater viewer count than InfoWars.

Also, other metrics are relatively similar. The average visit length is between 3-4 minutes and CNN has 77% US traffic while InfoWars has 75%. The pages per visit are both between 2-3.

Keep in mind that this is an assumption, not cold hard fact, but due to CNN having 80x more traffic with similar metrics it is most likely correct.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/) Please [provide specific references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims.

Comment: Yeah Infowars not doing greatly today. But the Q is about the height of their popularity.

Answer (score -8):

CNN had around 800k viewers a day, at its all time peak. Ever.

Infowars gets over 500k visits per day not unique users so we can estimate unique users can be 300k, now. We're not even talking peak numbers. And his traffic is way down from all time highs.

So yes, Infowars, at its peak, got more traffic than CNN's TV news network.

Comment: Welcome to our Stackexchange. We require citations for statements like what you are making

Comment: I am confused how you concluded that 500k visits = 300k unique users, and how 300k viewers > 800k viewers.

Comment: @Oddthinking: appears to be copied from https://www.reddit.com/r/KnowledgeFight/comments/1bqbpk0/can_a_policy_wonk_help_answer_this_did_more/ without the refs though.